# jqgrid forms label alignment issue

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am developing an ASP.Net based application using JQGrid. 
During development I am facing label alignment issue in jqgrid when ever opening Add/Edit form.

### Below are my code snipped:

```
jQuery(function () {

        $.extend(true, $.jgrid.edit, {
            recreateForm: true,
            beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
                $form.closest(".ui-jqdialog").position({
                    of: window,
                    my: "center center",
                    at: "center center"
                });
            }
        });

        jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid({
            url: 'JQGridHandler.ashx',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['DemandId', 'Account', 'POC', 'COE', 'Type', 'Location', 'OppotunityName', 'Designation', 'Experience', 'ExpectedRole', 'PrimarySkill', 'SecondarySkill', 'OtherSkill', 'RequiredDate', 'EndDate', 'Probable %', 'CriticalFlag', 'AssignedFlag', 'ConfidenceFactor', 'HiringSO', 'SOId', 'Comments', "# of Positions"],
            colModel: [
                            { name: 'DemandId', index: 'DemandId', width: '5%', align: 'center', sortable: true, resizable: true, editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: true }, formoptions: { rowpos: 1, colpos: 1} },
                            { name: 'AccountName', index: 'AccountName', width: '10%', sortable: true, resizable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 1, colpos: 2 }, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: { 0: '', 1: 'ASTRA ZENECA', 2: 'GSK'}} },
                            { name: 'AccountPOC', index: 'AccountPOC', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { rowpos: 1, colpos: 3, elmsuffix: "(<span class='mystar' style='color:red'>*</span>)"} },
                            { name: 'COE', index: 'COE', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 2, colpos: 1 }, editable: true, editrules: { required: true} },
                            { name: 'DemandType', index: 'DemandType', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 2, colpos: 2 }, editable: true, editrules: { required: true} },
                            { name: 'Location', index: 'Location', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, editable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 2, colpos: 3 }, editable: true, editrules: { required: true} },
                            { name: 'OppotunityName', index: 'OppotunityName', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 3, colpos: 1 }, editable: true, editrules: { required: true} },
                            { name: 'Designation', index: 'Designation', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 3, colpos: 2 }, editable: true, editrules: { required: true} },
                            { name: 'Experience', index: 'Experience', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, search: false, formoptions: { rowpos: 3, colpos: 3 }, editable: true, editrules: { required: true} },
                            { name: 'ExpectedRole', index: 'ExpectedRole', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, editable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 4, colpos: 1} },
                            { name: 'PrimarySkill', index: 'PrimarySkill', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 4, colpos: 2 }, editable: true, editrules: { required: true} },
                            { name: 'SecondarySkill', index: 'SecondarySkill', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 4, colpos: 3 }, editable: true },
                            { name: 'OtherSkill', index: 'OtherSkill', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 5, colpos: 1 }, editable: true },
                            { name: 'RequiredDate', index: 'RequiredDate', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 5, colpos: 2 }, editable: true, "formatter": "date", "formatoptions": { "srcformat": "Y-m-d H:i:s", "newformat": "m\/d\/Y" }, "editoptions": { "dataInit": function (el) { setTimeout(function () { if (jQuery.ui) { if (jQuery.ui.datepicker) { jQuery(el).after('<button>Calendar</button>').next().button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-calendar' }, text: false }).css({ 'font-size': '75%' }).click(function (e) { jQuery(el).datepicker('show'); return false; }); jQuery(el).datepicker({ "disabled": false, "dateFormat": "dd\/mm\/yy" }); jQuery('.ui-datepicker').css({ 'font-size': '75%' }); } } }, 100); } }, editrules: { required: true} },
                            { name: 'EndDate', index: 'EndDate', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 5, colpos: 3 }, editable: true, "formatter": "date", "formatoptions": { "srcformat": "Y-m-d H:i:s", "newformat": "m\/d\/Y" }, "editoptions": { "dataInit": function (el) { setTimeout(function () { if (jQuery.ui) { if (jQuery.ui.datepicker) { jQuery(el).after('<button>Calendar</button>').next().button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-calendar' }, text: false }).css({ 'font-size': '75%' }).click(function (e) { jQuery(el).datepicker('show'); return false; }); jQuery(el).datepicker({ "disabled": false, "dateFormat": "dd\/mm\/yy" }); jQuery('.ui-datepicker').css({ 'font-size': '75%' }); } } }, 100); } } },
                            { name: 'ProbablePercentage', index: 'ProbablePercentage', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 6, colpos: 1 }, editable: true },
                            { name: 'CriticalFlag', index: 'CriticalFlag', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 6, colpos: 2 }, editable: true },
                            { name: 'AssignedFlag', index: 'AssignedFlag', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 6, colpos: 3 }, editable: true },
                            { name: 'ConfidenceFactor', index: 'ConfidenceFactor', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 7, colpos: 1 }, editable: true },
                            { name: 'HiringSO', index: 'HiringSO', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 7, colpos: 2 }, editable: true },
                            { name: 'HiringSOId', index: 'HiringSOId', width: '5%', sortable: true, resizable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 7, colpos: 3 }, editable: true },
                            { name: 'Comments', index: 'Comments', width: '5%', sortable: false, resizable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 8, colpos: 1 }, editable: true, edittype: "textarea", editoptions: { rows: "5", cols: "19"} },
                            { name: 'QTY', index: 'QTY', editable: true, hidden: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 8, colpos: 2 }, editrules: { edithidden: true }, editoptions: { defaultValue: '1'} }
                      ],
            width: '1170',
            height: '500',
            loadonce: true,
            pager: '#pagerDiv',
            gridview: true,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            rowTotal: 500,
            sortorder: 'desc',
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'Latest Demands',
            emptyrecords: "No records to view",
            loadtext: "Loading...",
            refreshtext: "Refresh",
            refreshtitle: "Reload Grid",
            loadComplete: loadCompleteHandler
        });


        jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
            stringResult: true,
            searchOnEnter: false,
            defaultSearch: 'cn'
        }); /* search strategy meaning: contains */
        jQuery("#listTable").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pagerDiv',
        {
            refresh: true, add: true, addtext: "Add", edit: true, edittext: "Edit", del: true, deltext: "Delete"
        },
        { width: 800, height: 330, recreateForm: true },
        { width: 800, height: 330, recreateForm: true },
        {}
        );
    });
```

### Issue:

Here "# of Positions" label is not aligned with its textbox.

[image: Alignment issue is shown in the picture]

So, please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the line

```js
$form.find("#tr_Comments .CaptionTD").css({verticalAlign: "top", paddingTop: ".5em"});
```

in `beforeShowForm` to have other alignment as for "Comments".